# java webpart like asp.net?

Tags: java, asp.net, web-parts, personalization

I was reading asp.net webpart technology which gives users some personalization abilities under some rules and tools of webparts.

are there something like webpart technology lib under java ?

Answer (score 1):

There's always the ill-fated [Portlet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portlet).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any JSF or JSP implementations of this, and I don't think they even exist.

It is, however, possible to create such a thing with [GWT from Google](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/) and [GWT-Dnd](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-dnd/) .
These let you create javascript webapplications, but you write them in Java.

Here's an example created with GWT-DND: http://www.wibokr.com

Answer (score 0):

- You can use the following stuff:

  - JSP
  - JSF (or any other implementation -    Icefaces, Richfaces, MyFaces, etc)
  - Google Web Toolkit
  - Spring MVC
  - Template-based solution (Freemarker    or Velocity)

Answer (score 0):

Haven't seen any frameworks which would directly support such functionality beyond the very basics, but there's a lot of frameworks which enable you to develop such a system if you want to. From other answers only the GWT and Portlet ones are actually valid so far.

If you want to find something compatible, you should start searching for web frameworks which support either of the Portlet API specifications ([1.0 is JSR-168](http://www.jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=168), [2.0 is JSR-286](http://www.jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=286)). Otherwise you just may as well roll out your own based on the web framework you find most comfortable to work with, whether that's [GWT](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/), [Seam](http://sfwk.org/), [Wicket](http://wicket.apache.org/), [Tapestry](http://tapestry.apache.org/), [Vaadin](http://vaadin.com/home)...